# what is RT_PREEMPT? how is it different from preempt rt ?does these mean same real time patch to linux?

Tags: linux, real-time

I presently working on hardrealtime linux.
when i search regarding documentation of topic RT_PREEMPT .
different sites turn up with different names like preempt-rt,rt-preempt.

can someone say me the exact link or any resources which could help me look on RT_PREEMPT?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the RT_Preempt patch, which is documented [here](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). The patch makes the kernel fully preemptable, and also includes some RT schedulers. It includes a how-to for installing it. If you are familiar with building kernels it should be pretty easy.

I documented my installation on my Ubuntu machine [here](http://home.gwu.edu/~jcmarsh/wiki/pmwiki.php%3Fn=Notes.RTPatch.html).

It is kinda difficult to find up-to-date information on the patch in part because much of it has become mainline in the last few years (having multiple names doesn't help either). For example, the 3.14 kernel has configuration options for a "low-latency" install.

Steven Rostedt gave a good overview talk in 2013 at the Embedded Linux Conference, available at [linuxgizmos.com](http://linuxgizmos.com/adding-real-time-to-linux-with-preempt-rt/) and [youtube](http://youtu.be/n9ucTGWrON8). Slides [here](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/images/stories/slides/elc2013_rostedt.pdf) (pdf). Around minute 17 he really starts to get into the differences:

- Interrupts are handled with threads (thus scheduled)
- Spin locks replaced with mutexes
- Priority inheritance is extended to the kernel

Comment: any links/resources for understanding internal implementation?source code documentation...

Comment: Edited. For source code documentation... well, you have the source itself! (Sorry, that isn't the most helpful response)

Comment: I am looking for some contribution for real time linux which majorly involves RT_PRREMPT patch . The wiki page of RT are pretty old i,e it says its been updated last at 2008

Also there are no wish list or bug list specific to RT _Preempt

Even bug zilla also doesn't have much on rt preempt?

Any resource pointing towards bugs ,features that are to be added to RT_preempt would be a lot of help

Comment: +1 for a good answer and a link to the talk on youtube